The page is refreshing when message sent ? e.preventDefault() is not working
I created a chatbot in which, first, I'll receive a response. In the form, there is a last field that has a value, and I want to send that value as a user message. The bot is working fine, but when I click on 'chatsubmit,' it refreshes the page. e.preventDefault() is not working because it is false, but without false, I can't send the values.
JS:
const submitForm = async (e, val) => {
    if (e) { e.preventDefault(); }

    if (!conversationId) {
        console.error('conversationId is not set.');
        return;
    }

    document.querySelector("#chat-submit").disabled = true;

    let x = document.forms["form-feedback-data"]["message"];
    let message = val || x.value;

    console.log('Submitting message:', message);

    // Send user message to API
    await sendToApi(conversationId, "user", message);

    if (message !== "") {
        let aud = new Audio("https://backend.aiduals.com/assets/userMusic.mp3");
        aud.play();

        // Display user message in chat window
        let userDiv = `
            <div class="aidual_chatbot_wrap">
                <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: end;">
                    <div>
                        <span class="aidual_chatbot_date2">
                            <strong>${guestName.length > 0 ? guestName : "Guest"}</strong> ${generateDate()}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="aidual_chatbot_wimg2">
                        <img src="${avtarUrl.length > 0 ? avtarUrl : "https://backend.aiduals.com/assets/user.png"}" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="aidual_chatbot_wchat2">
                    ${message}
                </div>
            </div>`;

        let blinkMsg = `
            <div style="display: flex; padding-left: 0px;" id="typing-feed-active">
                <span style="color: #555; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; display: flex; margin-top: 6px;">
                    <span style="margin-right: 5px">Do Tasks AI</span> is <span id="blinkChangeMsg" style="margin-left: 5px">typing</span>
                </span>
                <div class="typing">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>`;

        typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
            typingIndex++;
            if (typingIndex === 6) {
                typingIndex = 0;
            }
            let typingMsgData = document.getElementById("blinkChangeMsg");
            typingMsgData.innerText = arrTyping[typingIndex];
        }, 5000);

        const chatWindow = document.getElementById("mainChatWindowBlock");
        chatWindow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", userDiv);
        chatWindow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", blinkMsg);
        if (chatWindow.clientHeight < chatWindow.scrollHeight) {
            chatWindow.scrollBy(0, chatWindow.scrollHeight);
        }

        // Call onCreateMessage to get AI response
        onCreateMessage(message, typingInterval);

        if (!val) {
            x.value = "";
        }
    }
}

async function onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loader.style.display = "inline-block";

    // Gather form data
    const data = {
        name: document.forms["form-data-main"]['name'].value,
        email: document.forms["form-data-main"]['email'].value,
        phone: document.forms["form-data-main"]['phone'].value,
        text: document.forms["form-data-main"]['message'].value,
    };

    // Store the guest name
    guestName = data.name;
    let value = data.text;

    removeMsg();
    document.querySelector("#form-container-box").style.display = "none";
    mainWindow.style.display = "block";
    chatBox.style.display = "block";

    try {
        // Send POST request to create a conversation
        const response = await fetch("https://dotasks.in/api/create-conversation", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        const result = await response.json();

        if (result.status) {
            conversationId = result.cid;
            console.log('The conversation id is:', conversationId);
            // Store feedData in a cookie
            feedData = { cid: conversationId };
            document.cookie = `feedData=${JSON.stringify(feedData)}`;

            // Fetch the conversation
            // await fetchChatData(conversationId);
            newFeed = feedData;
            submitForm(false, value);  // value is going from here

            // Clear form fields
            document.forms["form-data-main"]['name'].value = "";
            document.forms["form-data-main"]['email'].value = "";
            document.forms["form-data-main"]['phone'].value = "";
            document.forms["form-data-main"]['message'].value = "";
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to create conversation:", result.message);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating conversation:", error);
    } finally {
        loader.style.display = "none";
    }

};

HTML:
<div class="">
<div class="message-input">
    <form class="message_input_wrap" id="form-feedback-data">
        <!--<span class="chat_icon"><img-->
        <!--        src="https://reeelapps-app.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aistaff/hire_staff_img/chat-icon.png"-->
        <!--        alt="" /></span>-->
        <input type="text" class="chat_typing_box"
            placeholder="Write your message..." name="message" required />
            
        <!--<div class="voice-icon-wrapper">-->
        <!--    <i id="start-btn" class="chat-send fa-solid fa-microphone"-->
        <!--        onclick="startRecognition()">-->
        <!--    </i>-->
        <!--    <i id="stop-btn" style="display:none;"-->
        <!--        class="chat-send fa-solid fa-pause" onclick="startRecognition()">-->
        <!--    </i>-->
        <!--</div>-->
            
        <button class="chat-send" type="submit" id="chat-submit"><img
                src="https://reeelapps-app.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Reputor_ai/send.png"
                alt="" /></button>
                
                
    </form>
</div>

I want to submit the form first, then receive the value as user input, and the page should not refresh when I send the message.

You never call submitForm().

Is there a missing addEventListener() call?
